# define x values for hc_add_series_list in highcharter

Tags: r, list, highcharts, r-highcharter

I want to define the x-values for a highcharter line plot, as I have categorial x-values and also sometimes values which refer to the same categorie. Anyway on highcharter it is possible as in this example on 15th of December shows: https://whatukthinks.org/eu/questions/should-the-united-kingdom-remain-a-member-of-the-eu-or-leave-the-eu/?removed . 
With the function hc_add_series I'm able to define the x values as you can see in the example below:

```
library(highcharter)
df = data_frame(x = c(1,1,3,3,5:7),y = c(100,105,110,120,80,90,98),name = 
c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B"))

hc2 <- highchart() %>%
    hc_add_series(df)

hc2
```

In my case, I don't know how many series there will be in the begin, so I want to use hc_add_series_list as I can define the list beforehand. But then I can't define the x-value, as data is always interpreted as the y value. after I read https://dantonnoriega.github.io/ultinomics.org/post/2017-04-05-highcharter-explainer.html I think it should be possible with sublists, but until now I'm not really sucessfull. I tried it like that:

```
ds_new <- lapply((1:1), function(x){
  list(name = paste(trips_of_choice[x]),
       data = list(x = c(1:2),
                   y = c(1:2),
                   name =c("5.TA.26-3-j19-1.5.R")
       ))
})
```

So to have a list with sublists which is named data and include x and y data. But it doesn't work at all.

I hope someone can help me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your series are stored in a list:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4),
                  y = c(100,105,110,120),
                  name = c("A","A","A","A"))
df2 <- data.frame(x = c(3:6),
                  y = c(80,90,98,105),
                  name = c("B","B","B","B"))
series_list <- list(df1, df2)
```

You can plot all the series using this solution:

```
hc2 <- highchart()
for (k in 1:length(series_list)) {
   hc2 <- hc2 %>%
          hc_add_series(series_list[[k]])
}
hc2
```

[image]

Comment: so far so good, I think this is a nice work around for the first problem, but I still fight if I have categories on the xAxis, for example: df1 <- data.frame(x = c("A","B","C","D","E"),y = c(100,105,110,120,120)), I tried it then with hc_xAxis(categories = df1$x), but this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @silvio91 This is a different question. I suggest to post it on SO with a reproducible example.